# Why am I getting an error when running my php code using dompdf?

Tags: php, html, dompdf, pdf-conversion

I am attempting to use dompdf to convert my html document to pdf. However, I am receiving the following error code:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\dompdf\pdf.php on line 6

My code is below:

```
<?php

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php'

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();

?>
```

I used the following documentation to help develop the above code:
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Answer (score 0):

Just add `;` after `require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php'`